# How to submit forms via Ajax in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, workflow

I'm just wondering how to submit forms with Ajax in Laravel

Laravel itself doesn't provide useful tips or workflow in its documentation

Is there some usefull library idealy as extension of jquery?

Im searching for unobtrusive javasctipt solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for https://github.com/whipsterCZ/laravel-ajax

It does exactly what you want **and much more**!

sending forms via ajax is simple like this - no configuration needed

HTML

```
<form action="" class="ajax">...</form>
```

Controller

```
public function update(ClientRequest $request, Client $client)
{
    $client->update($request->all());
    $request->session()->flash('success', 'Client has been updated.');

    return \Ajax::redirect(route('clients.index'));
}
```

It also validate form (through custom FormRequest) and shows errors  (in errorBag or directly above inputs)

Comment: It is basicaly AJAX Workflow for Laravel. If you are familiar with **Nette Framework** you are at home...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
                      {
                       $(document).on('submit', '#reg-form', function()
                       {
                      var data = $(this).find("#post_id").val();
                        $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url  : '{{url("/ajax")}}',
                       data: {'name':data, '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
                       success: function(data) {
                       //do stuff
                      },

                            error :  function(data)
                            {
                                alert("Fix thist");
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                       });

                      });
```

**Controller**

```
if (\Request::ajax()) {
    // Do stuff
            return response()->json('success');
        }
```

Whats wrong with such an exemple?

Answer (score 0):

In the same domain

My form.blade.php

```
<form action=""  id="contact-form" class="form-contact">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email"id="contact_email"   placeholder="Email">
    <textarea name="message"  id="contact_message"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="bnt-submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

My function.js

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(){
     formulario =  $("#contact-form");
          url =  "http:://MyDomin/sendContacto";
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: formulario.serialize()
                    })
                        .done(function( response ) {
                            msg = ' <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'+arrMsgs[lang]["message_send"]+'</div>';
                            $("#messages").append(msg);
                        });
})
```

Add routes sendContact in routes.php and  asign a function `sencContacto`

In My Contrller@sendcontacto

```
public function sendContacto(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input("name");
    $email = $request->input("email");
    $message = $request->input("message");
//Do something
}
```